# Prepare sub directory before saving uploaded file in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is a method we used before saving a uploaded file in Rails 4.2:

```
   def prepare_subdir()     
       dir = Rails.root.join(@uploaded_file.storage_subdir).to_s
       FileUtils.mkdir_p(dir) unless File.directory?(dir)
   end
```

In debugging:

```
dir = "/upload/ext_construction_projectx_project/17"
@uploaded_file.storage_subdir = "/upload/ext_construction_projectx_project/17"
File.directory?(dir) returns true, even though only sub directory /upload/ exists on file system. No directory /ext_construction_projectx_project and 17 exist.
```

We found no file saved after clicking `Save`. Do we need to make sure all sub directories including `ext_construction_projectx_project` and `17` have to be created before calling to save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without a leading slash, like this:

```
dir = "upload/ext_construction_projectx_project/17"
```

of course, unless your upload dir is actually a subdir of root:

```
[1] pry(main)> dir = "/upload/ext_construction_projectx_project/17"
=> "/upload/ext_construction_projectx_project/17"
[2] pry(main)> Rails.root.join(dir)
=> #<Pathname:/upload/ext_construction_projectx_project/17>
[3] pry(main)> dir = "upload/ext_construction_projectx_project/17"
=> "upload/ext_construction_projectx_project/17"
[4] pry(main)> Rails.root.join(dir)
=> #<Pathname:/home/m/ruby/rails_app/upload/ext_construction_projectx_project/17>
```

Comment: can you please include that save method? Or do you call prepare_subdir in a callback? Do you use ActiveRecord? If so, is there any exception if you replace `save` with `save!` ?

Comment: The same leading `\\` caused problem in saving. After removing leading `\\`, now it saves. Many thanks.